# Count the number of pixels by color from an image loaded into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to count the number pixels in a weather radar image for each dbz reflectivity level (the colored blocks of green, orange, yellow, red, etc.) so I can "score" the radar image based on the type of echos.

I'm new to numpy and numpy arrays, but I know it can be very efficient when I'm working with the individual pixels in an image, so I'd like to learn more.

I'm not even sure I'm selecting the pixels correctly, but I think I'm getting close.

I have a sample of using both numpy and basic pixel iteration to count the number of green pixels with an RGBA of (1, 197, 1, 255).

Hopefully I'm close and someone can give me guidance on how to select the pixels using numpy and then count them:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import urllib2
import sys

color_dbz_20 = (2, 253, 2, 255)
color_dbz_25 = (1, 197, 1, 255)
color_dbz_30 = (0, 142, 0, 255)

url = 'http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/DLH_N0R_0.gif'
image_bytes = io.BytesIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

image = PIL.Image.open(image_bytes)
image = image.convert('RGBA')

total_pixels = image.height * image.width

# Count using numpy
np_pixdata = np.array(image)

# Didn't work, gave me the total size:
# np_counter = np_pixdata[(np_pixdata == color_dbz_20)].size

np_counter = np.count_nonzero(np_pixdata[(np_pixdata == color_dbz_20)])

# Count using pillow
pil_pixdata = image.load()

pil_counter = 0
for y in xrange(image.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(image.size[0]):
        if pil_pixdata[x, y] == color_dbz_20:
            pil_counter += 1

print "Numpy Count: %d" % np_counter
print "Pillow Count: %d" % pil_counter
```

Output:

```
Numpy Count: 134573
Pillow Count: 9967
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `numpy` array will be an array of size `X * Y * 4` but you compare each element with a tuple - but it's only a number. That's the reason why your:

```
 np_counter = np_pixdata[(np_pixdata == color_dbz_20)].size
```

didn't exclude any elements.

That you got different counts in the end is because you counted `nonzero`-elements. But there are zeros in some array elements, just for one color but nevertheless 0 - which are excluded even though you don't want that!

First you want to compare numpy arrays so better convert the `color`-tuples too:

```
color_dbz_20 = np.array([2, 253, 2, 255]), ...
```

To get the real result for your condition you must use `np.all` along axis=2:

```
np.all(np_pixdata == color_dbz_20, axis=2)
```

This checks if the values along axis 2 (colors) are equal to the ones in your `color_dbz_20` and this for each pixel. To get the sum of all the matches:

```
np.sum(np.all(np_pixdata == color_dbz_20, axis=2)) # Sum of boolean array is integer!
```

which gives you the number of pixel where the condition is True. True is interpreted as 1 and False as 0 - that way doing the sum will work - alternativly you could also `count_nonzero` instead of `sum` here. Always assuming you created your `color_dbz_20`-array as `np.array`.

Maybe the image has a different dimensionality and it's not `width * height * depth` then you just need to adjust the `axis` in the `np.all` to the dimension where the `colors` are (the one with length `4`).